# Where does the expression to calculate the final $V$ in a capacitor come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, voltage

I would like to know where the expression to calculate the final Voltage of a capacitor in a circuit with 2 resistors comes from. So far, I know the equation is:

*$$V_{final} = E \times \frac{R2}{(R1 +R2)}$$*

My circuit is of the form:

Source - R1 - R2 = C where "-" is a connection in series and "=" a parallel one.

Comment: You should clarify the actual distribution of elements inside the circuit. It's not the same if they're in series, or parallel, or mixed.

Comment: The resistors are in parallel and then the capacitor is in series with them both

Comment: @sysfiend, if your description of the circuit is correct, the final voltage across the capacitor would simply be $E$.

Comment: The given formula is consistent with the two resistors being in series with the voltage source and the capacitor in parallel with resistor $R_2$. The two resistors act as a potential divider.

Comment: yes, sorry, my bad, R1 is in series with the source and R2 and the capacitor are in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule for these RC transient problems, to find the final value of the voltage across the capacitor, simply *remove the capacitor from the circuit* and then calculate the voltage across the now open terminals where the capacitor was connected.

Why?  In DC steady state, the voltage across the capacitor is *constant* and thus, the current through the capacitor is *zero*.

The equation you provide in your question would be the formula for the final voltage across the capacitor in the case that $R2$ is in parallel with the capacitor and $R1$ is in series with the voltage source.  For example:

[image]